# What Do The Ending Letters Mean - pythonw, javaw, javap, javac, etc

Tags: java, python, javaw, pythonw

I just made a connection between python's: `pythonw.exe` and java's: `javaw.exe` and I'm curious about this as I cant figure out what some of those ending letters mean. I know that `javac` is the Java compiler so I assume the `w` on the end of the name also has some significance. I've also seen more like `javap`, `javah` etc. Could someone outline the meanings for the most common endings like c, w, h, p, etc?

I've tried googling and searching on Stackoverflow but haven't found anything that isn't just about a specific ending.

Edit:

I realize there are a lot of isolated answers to these questions. All I really want to know is if there's a place where I can view a complete (or decent) list of the common letters and their meanings, or if someone could outline them for me? Also what to call these endings so that I'm not referring to them just "ending letters"?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4861523/what-does-p-in-javap-stand-for

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194713/difference-between-java-javaw-javaws

Comment: "windows" - that won't open a command prompt when executed ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705982/pythonw-exe-or-python-exe

Answer (score 4):

By default `java` opens a console window when executed in windows OS. By using `javaw` the java process doesn't open in a console window. It is a good UX practice to use `javaw` in scripts or bundled executables. I guess it is the same for `pythonw` also. 'w' stands for 'Windows' as in Java for windows.

Answer (score 3):

The difference between python.exe and pythonw.exe is terminal suppression. When you execute a script with pythonw.exe, no terminal windows is opened, which is nice if you wrote a program that uses a GUI and you don't want an additional terminal window to show

See here for more info: https://docs.python.org/2/using/windows.html#executing-scripts

Comment: That answers my question about the w but what about all the other letters? And the ones I didn't even mention

Answer (score 1):

There're no "*common endings*", it depends on developers what they decide to use to name their executables.

In case of Java, here are various Java 8 executable suffixes:

> - **`java`**: The launcher for Java applications. In this release, a single launcher is used both for development and deployment.
>     The old deployment launcher, `jre`, is no longer provided.
> - **`javac`**: The compiler for the Java programming language.
> - **`javah`**: C header and stub generator. Used to write native methods.
> - **`javap`**: Class file disassembler.
> - **`javaw`**: The `javaw` command is identical to java, except that with `javaw` there is no associated console window. Use `javaw` when you do not want a command prompt window to appear. The `javaw` launcher will, however, display a dialog box with error information if a launch fails.
> - **`javaws`**: Command line tool for launching Java Web Start and setting various options.

(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/#basic)